# How to checkout an empty directory from CVS in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, repository, cvs

Some one has created an empty package in CVS. 
I want to checkout this package in Intellij but nothing appears in intellij.

**Does any one know why and how to solve it?**

Comment: ...my first solution would be to migrate from CVS to either git or mercurial, and not tackle any CVS problem ever again. But if that is not an option, I seem to remember cvs had command line switch, possibly -p for prune, which determines if empty directories are created. So, man cvs, then dig into IntelliJ CVS options... And if you do find solution by this hint, it's fine if you answer your own question with details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to uncheck option `Prune empty directories` in checkout IntelliJ IDEA CVS wizard.